# SQL Connection: Server Not Found or Access Denied when Connecting from Client PC

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlconnection

I'm having an issue with an SQL database connection from client pc to the server pc. FYI, I am not an SQL-wiz.

I'm using a cashier program called (الأمين), and there is not enough support for this problem. When I try to connect to the main server through the client pc, I receive the following error:

> [DBNETLIB] [ConnectionOpen (Connect().]SQL Server does not exist or access denied

I already tried the following fixes:

1. Windows firewall inbound and outbound rules for ports 1433 and 1434.
2. Client Utility Management, I enabled the TCP/IP and kept the named pipes disabled. I added the appropriate server name and I added the IP of the server as alias. (This is on the Client PC)
3. I enabled the TCP/IP on the SQL server configuration and added 1433 under IPAll and IP1.
4. I made sure that the password and user names being logged in with were correct from the client pc.
5. I made sure "Allow Remote Connection" was turned on in the server settings.

I could've also tried some more fixes already but can't recall them right now.

Please, any help would be appreciated. I just need the client PC to connect to the server PC. The problem could be from the cashier program itself, but it works for other users of the same software. There isn't enough support for the program so I have to fix it myself. I am convinced there is a simple solution that I just don't see.

Thank you plenty in advance!

I am using version 18.8 SQL Server Management Studio, and am on windows 10.

Comment: *"I am using version 18.8 SQL Server Management Studio"* But what version of SQL Server? You*have* installed SQL Server, correct? SSMS <> SQL Server.

Comment: _"Windows firewall inbound and outbound rules for ports 1433 and 1434."_ So that's tcp/1433 for a default SQL Server instance (e.g.: FooBarBaz\MSSQLSERVER) and udp/1434 for the SQL Browser service, right? They're not both TCP ports.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning no. Both ports are TCP.

Comment: @A.H.Alwagdani FYI the SQL Browser service operates on udp/1434. Ref: [Resolving connectivity errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/solving-connectivity-errors#cause-5named-instance-udp-port-1434-used-by-sql-browser-is-blocked-on-the-network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

The problem was with the login of SQL.

I logged in using "sa" the user made with the SQL creation and it works now.

Thank you!